# What is the meaning of referent_id in a SMB2/DCERPC SRVSVC NetSessEnum request?

Tags: rpc, smb, dce

I'm trying to dissect a NetSessEnum request over SMB2 (srvsvc opnum 12)
According to Wireshark, a field called Referent_ID seems to have a value of 0x00020000. I can't find proper documentation regarding this field. I'd like to know, if only 0x00020000 is a valid value for this operation or not. Will appreciate pointer to proper documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This field is a serialization mark and it may have any value. For instance in our rpc implementation we are using running numbers. This field means a reference and the referenced value comes later according to the serialization rules. The value is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this.

Comment: > the referenced value comes later according to the serialization rules. What do you mean ?

Comment: struct s1 { 
 int f1;
 struct s2 * f2;
 int f3;
}
The above data is serialized as 1) f1 value  2) ref id for f2 3) f3 value 4) s2 contents.
Hope this helps.